# Key point matching within one image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, flann, keypoint

I am using open-cv with python for doing image processing stuff and have found plenty of examples of keypoint matching from two images. The image I'm working with has similar object in it and I am finding hard time to perform key point matching in that single image. Can anybody got any idea how to do it?

Comment: Crop the image into two or more parts and then do it in pairs. Or make two copies and mask out one or the other so you can process again in pairs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions though I already considered those options just wondering if there is any straight forward way to do that ...